# down time while adding read-replica in mysql rds

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

When i add read replica in MySQL RDS database will other read replicas have downtime?
What happens in case of RDS aurora?

Comment: In regular MySQL, I would take one Replica, clone it (by some means), then put it into service.  The cloning would have some impact on the source Replica, but not on the Primary or other Replicas.  I trust that RDS/Aurora has not screwed this up.

Answer (score 1):

**User Guide:** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html

When you create a read replica, Amazon RDS takes a DB snapshot of your source DB instance and begins replication. As a result, you experience a brief I/O suspension on your source DB instance while the DB snapshot occurs.

**Note:**
The I/O suspension typically lasts about one minute. You can avoid the I/O suspension if the source DB instance is a Multi-AZ deployment, because in that case the snapshot is taken from the secondary DB instance.